# How to access correct 'this' inside map: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example I have a react component with two binding methods:

```
import React from 'react';

class Comments extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleRemoveComment = this.handleRemoveComment.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        .....
    }

    handleRemoveComment(e) {
        //this.props.removeComment(null, this.props.params, i);
    }

    renderComment(comment, i) {
        return(
            <div className="comment" key={i}>
                  .....
                  <button 
                       onClick={this.handleRemoveComment}
                       className="remove-comment">
                       &times;
                  </button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="comments">

                {this.props.postComments.map(this.renderComment)}

                .....
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Comments;
```

In above code, I have two binding method: one is `handleSubmit` and one is `handleRemoveComment`. `handleSubmit` function worked but `handleRemoveComment` doesn't. When running, It returns error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleRemoveComment' of undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is with this line:

```
{this.props.postComments.map( this.renderComment )}
```

Because you forgot to bind `renderComment`, map callback method, so `this` inside `renderComment` method will not refer to the class context.

Use **any one** of these solutions, it will work.

**1-** Use this line in `constructor`:

```
this.renderComment = this.renderComment.bind(this) ;
```

**2-** Pass `this` with with `map` like:

```
{this.props.postComments.map(this.renderComment, this)}
```

**3-** Use Arrow function with `renderComment` method, like this:

```
renderComment = (comment, i) => {
    .....
```

or use the map inside the `renderComment` function (i used to prefer this way), like this:

```
renderComment() {
    return this.props.postComments.map((comment, i) => {
        return(
            <div className="comment" key={i}>
                <p>
                    <strong>{comment.user}</strong>
                    {comment.text}
                    <button 
                        onClick={this.handleRemoveComment}
                        className="remove-comment">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

And call this method from `render`, in this case binding of `renderComment` is not required:

```
{this.renderComment()}
```

Comment: ...or just add `, this` in the call to `map`: `{this.props.postComments.map(this.renderComment, this)}`

Comment: Wow. thanks so much. I think there is some problem in `handleRemoveComment` because error message. I have two questions:
1. why can you know error in `renderComment` (by reading source code carefully or by your experience ...)
2. If I remove code `onClick={this.handleRemoveComment}`, no error found.

Comment: reason is: if you don't bind the context then `this` keyword (refer to class) will not be available inside `map` body, that why when you removed the `removeComment` it is working, if you want to use `this` keyword you need to bind the context. By reading the source code its a very common issue with map body :)

Comment: check the updated answer, you can try any one solution, Thanks @T.J.Crowder for very simple solution :)