# React Recursion

Tags: reactjs, recursion

Im trying to let a function call itself to do some recursion. But I cant seem to find out how to access the function from within itself. Probably a syntax problem - can anyone help?. It throws 
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'recursiveRenderChildren' of undefined*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ComposeDom extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.recursiveRenderChildren(this.props.cdom.treeData)}
        </div>
    }
    recursiveRenderChildren(children) {
        return children.map(function(child){
            console.log(child);
            return <child.slug key={child.title}>{child.title} {this.recursiveRenderChildren(child.children)}</child.slug>
        })
}
```

Comment: In general there should be no issue "accessing the function from within itself".  So what is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Oh hi. Your quick. It does throw an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'recursiveCloneChildren' of undefined"

Comment: recursiveCloneChildren shouldn't this be recursiveRenderChildren

Comment: i think typo: you are calling `recursiveCloneChildren` instead of `recursiveRenderChildren`, check console it should throw the error.

Comment: Typo fixed - to no avail: still TypeError: Cannot read property 'recursiveRenderChildren' of undefined

Comment: binding issue, use arrow function: `return children.map((child) => {`   check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568344/typeerror-cannot-read-property-function-name-of-undefined-when-binding-onclic

Comment: @Phil I have posted the correct answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should be like this:-

```
recursiveRenderChildren(children) {
        let that = this;
        return children.map(function(child){
          console.log(child);
            return <child.slug key={child.title}>{child.title} {that.recursiveRenderChildren(child.children)}</child.slug>
        })
  }
```

Comment: storing the context in a separate variable is not required, we can use arrow function: `return children.map((child) => {`

Comment: @MayankShukla yes that's correct as well.Just wanted to make things easy for him to understand which is why stored context in another variable.

Comment: @Phil if the answer helped you, can you please mark it as the correct answer.Thanks.

Comment: @VivekN - thank your for pointing out the fundamental problem here in a simple manner :D

Comment: Happy to help... :)

Comment: @MayankShukla. And thx for going into detail here. I had the funciton itsel as a arrow-function but I didn't think of expressing the map-call as an arrow function - another side-mystery solved. ;)