# set state doesn't work in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function for set my states but it doesn't work correctly.

this is my function,

```
checkAnswer() {
  this.setState({
    isDropdownShown: false
  });
}
```

and i'm calling like this,

```
renderAnswers(answer, idx) {
  return (
    <li
      key={idx}
      className={styles.questionDropdownItem}
      onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(answer)}
    >
      {answer.title}
    </li>
  );
}
```

**From His Comment:**

I'm calling `renderAnswers` method in render like this:

```
{question.answers.map(this.renderAnswers)}
```

I'm try everything like shouldComponentUpdate but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your entire component? There are some important parts missing.

Comment: please show the entire class, including constructor.

Comment: i'm calling in render method like this, {question.answers.map(this.renderAnswers)}

Comment: `this.setState({
    isDropdownShown: false
  }, () => console.log(this.state.isDropdownShown);` what does this say?

Comment: it's returns true

Comment: @UgurcanOmur Please edit your post to contain the entire component.

Answer (score 1):

```
{question.answers.map(this.renderAnswers)}
```

should be

```
{question.answers.map(this.renderAnswers, this)}
```

or

```
{question.answers.map((answer, i) => this.renderAnswers(answer, i))}
```

Your first example will call the `renderAnswers` function with no `this` value because.map`has no way to know what`this` you'd want.

Comment: i think it a duplicate of [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568344/typeerror-cannot-read-property-function-name-of-undefined-when-binding-onclic) correct?

Comment: Yeah good call.